# Replacing string by incrementing number

Tags: regex, awk

**Input File**

```
AAAAAA this is some content.
This is AAAAAA some more content BBBBBB. BBBBBB BBBBBB
This is yet AAAAAA some more BBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBBB content.
```

I can accomplish this partially with this code:

```
awk '/AAAAAA/{gsub("AAAAAA", "x"++i)}1' test.txt > test1.txt
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/BBBBBB/){sub(/BBBBBB/,"y"++i)}}1' test1.txt
```

**Output:**

```
x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content y1. y2 y3
This is yet x3 some more y4 y5 y6 content.
```

Anyway to get this output?

**Expected Output:**

```
x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content y1. y2 y3
This is yet x3 some more y1 y2 y3 content.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to reset `i=0` after each loop:

```
awk '/AAAAAA/{gsub("AAAAAA", "x"++i)}1' test.txt > test1.txt
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x~/BBBBBB/){sub(/BBBBBB/,"y"++i)}{i=0}}1' test1.txt
```

Output:

```
x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content y1. y2 y3
This is yet x3 some more y1 y2 y3 content.
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this single `awk`:

```
awk '{
   j=0
   for (x=1; x<=NF; x++)
      if ($x ~ /^A{6}/)
         sub(/^A{6}/, "x" (++i), $x)
      else if ($x ~ /^B{6}/)
         sub(/^B{6}/, "y" (++j), $x)
} 1' file
```

```
x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content y1. y2 y3
This is yet x3 some more y1 y2 y3 content.
```

Answer (score 3):

another one

```
$ awk '{sub("AAAAAA","x"(++x)); y=0; while(sub("BBBBBB","y"(++y)));}1' file

x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content y1. y2 y3
This is yet x3 some more y1 y2 y3 content.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate `awk` that is easily extended to add as many tags as you wish:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ rep["AAAAAA"]="x"; cnts["AAAAAA"]=1; reset["AAAAAA"]=0
            rep["BBBBBB"]="y"; cnts["BBBBBB"]=1; reset["BBBBBB"]=1
            # and so on...
        }
        {   
            for (e in rep) {
                cnts[e]=(reset[e]) ? reset[e] : cnts[e] 
                while ( sub(e,rep[e] (cnts[e]++) ) )
                    ; # empty statement since work is inside the while
        }
        } 1' file
```

Prints:

```
x1 this is some content.
This is x2 some more content y1. y2 y3
This is yet x3 some more y1 y2 y3 content.
```